# Cloudflare Authenticated Origin Pulls With Kestrel Web Server(Linux)

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, cloudflare

I have tried to setup Authenticated Origin Pulls on Kestrel Server and block direct access to the rest API via IP address but still allows access via Direct IP.

appsetting.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "HttpsDefaults": {
      "ClientCertificateMode": "RequireCertificate"
    },
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:443",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "/home/ubuntu/domain.name.pfx",
          "Password": "12345",
          "AllowInvalid": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

MyCertificateValidationService.cs

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class MyCertificateValidationService
{
    public bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
    {
        var cert = new X509Certificate2("/home/ubuntu/cloudflare.pfx", "12345");
        return clientCertificate.Thumbprint == cert.Thumbprint;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ClientCertificateCheck
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
                        context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ClientCertificateCheck
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthentication(
                    CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCertificate(options =>
                {
                    options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                        {
                            var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                                .GetService<MyCertificateValidationService>();

                            if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                            {
                                context.Success();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                context.Fail("invalid cert");
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            context.Fail("invalid cert");
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
                Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
        }
        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCertificateForwarding();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
}
```

even after above setup when I access it via domain it goes all good but when I access it from IP address access should be actually blocked and I should be receiving `invalid cert` Message. Not able to identify where I am going wrong in this.

Edited:
I am not willing to use any reverse proxy like nginx or apache2 I want to achieve this using Kestrel only.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of core your are using but for 5.0

Kestrel supports SNI defined in configuration. An endpoint can be configured with an Sni object that contains a mapping between host names and HTTPS options. The connection host name is matched to the options and they are used for that connection.

The following configuration adds an endpoint named MySniEndpoint that uses SNI to select HTTPS options based on the host name

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "MySniEndpoint": {
        "Url": "https://*",
        "SslProtocols": ["Tls11", "Tls12"],
        "Sni": {
          "a.example.org": {
            "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2",
            "SslProtocols": ["Tls11", "Tls12", "Tls13"],
            "Certificate": {
              "Subject": "<subject; required>",
              "Store": "<certificate store; required>",
            },
            "ClientCertificateMode" : "NoCertificate"
          },
          "*.example.org": {
            "Certificate": {
              "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
              "Password": "<certificate password>"
            }
          },
          "*": {
            // At least one subproperty needs to exist per SNI section or it
            // cannot be discovered via IConfiguration
            "Protocols": "Http1",
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        "Password": "<certificate password>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Soure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Question is regarding blocking direct access via ip and enable certificate authentication so only authenticated calls from cloudflare can access server but with your answer you are still allowed to access ip by specifying host header in your client and no certificate authentication.

Comment: I believe that you are confusing HTTPS with certificate authentication. 
did you enable Hostname for Client Authentication on Cloudflare?

Comment: there is feature on cloud flare which sends certificate to your server to verify that request is coming from cloudflare that is know has  Authenticated pulls https certificate are different and origin pull stuff is different I have this setup working if I proxy requests through nginx proxy pass I have it setup their but now instead of proxying requests it would be better to use Kestrel server directly and read how this stuff work [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204899617-Authenticated-Origin-Pulls)

Comment: isnt the updated answer about https ? I am looking for Client Certificate Authentication :/ where this mode ClientCertificateMode is usually set to allowcertificate or requirecertificate you are still being confused that i need https stuff for my api but i need that certificate authentication.

Comment: Https and certificate authentication are two distinct things. On  Certificate Authentication you literally uses a certificate to authenticate something, like a user nane and password any client with the certificate will be a valid client, in the other hand you have https that is used to secure the connection between the host and client and enforce some extra validations like hostname, You said it work fine with reverse proxy on nginx right, it happen because it was configured to enforce https (reject any connection without a proper hostname or without one "IP only")

Comment: Thanks for the info. I could have been wrong regarding that stuff removing the downvote and got my solution by only allowing Cloudflare IP ranges from this [page](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) to my provider firewall on port 443 so only Cloudflare will be able to communicate with my server and won't have to worry about authenticating via a certificate or anything at the code level. Thanks for your time once again.